# KVO - interface orientation property

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe interface orientation by KVO of UIViewController from other object by this code :

```
[((UIViewController *)self.delegate) addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"interfaceOrientation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and implementing  the function :

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context 
{
 if ([keyPath isEqual:@"interfaceOrientation"]) 
  {
    // do something    
  }
}
```

The method is called only in the first time , although i can see that the property interfaceOrientation of the delegate change while i rotating the phone .

Why?

Please help !

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this with KVO? UIViewControllers have built in support for this. Look at

```
  //iOS6 only
 - (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods
 {
    return YES;
 }
```

and also `addChildViewController:`

Comment: if it is not a subview of the view of the view controller? it is a view that is a subview of the window.